# Why won't my code output what is required of the prompt?

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve the prompt given to me, but it keeps outputting something completely different than what I'm wanting:

```
air_temperature = float(input())

print('{air_temperature:.1f}C'.format(air_temperature = float(input())))
```

Here's the code, and the prompt is to get this `36.4158102` to `36.4C`.
The code is outputting `24.6C` and I have no clue how or why. I am unable to change `air_temperature = float(input())`  , so I'm not sure what to do.

I tried changing the code to `print('{float.(input()):.1f}C'.format(float(input())))`,
and still, nothing.

Comment: You are making the program ask for input twice. Maybe you confused the two inputs you entered?

Answer (score 0):

You're asking for input twice, and only printing the second response. Just use the variable you assigned in the first `input()` call.

```
air_temperature = float(input())

print(f'{air_temperature:.1f}C')
```

You can use an f-string instead of the more verbose `.format()`.